# Tuple containing 2 model lists, mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tuples

Can I pass 2 lists of tuples to a view ?

```
var tuple = new Tuple<List<ModelName1>, List<ModelName2>>(object1,object2);
```

where

```
object1 = new List<ModelName1>
object2 = new List<ModelName2>
```

These 2 objects I have already created.

Comment: I don't see why not... Are you trying something and it's failing?

Comment: HOw to access my models in the view while using the tuple?

Comment: `tuple.Item1` and `tuple.Item2`?